# How to test Java web service with JUnit?

Tags: java, web-services, junit, logic

I need to test a service by JUnit.

Here is my code :

```
public class AdviesBoxTestDaoImpl {
    private SearchDaoImpl  searchDaoImpl;
    private SearchParametersDto searchParametersDto;

    JSONObject jsonObject;


    @Before
    public void loadJsonFile(){
     try{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        searchParametersDto =  mapper.readValue(new File("D:\\productsData.json"), SearchParametersDto.class);
     }
     catch(Exception e){

     }
}


    @Test
    public void testsDemoMethod() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(searchParametersDto.toString());
        assertEquals( "Products saved successfully",
                searchDaoImpl.inTable(searchParametersDto));
    }
}
```

Result of my service is message as "Products saved successfully" in String which is I am comparing here.  Each time I run the test case , I get the NullPointerException Error.

What changes I should make in the code so that I can test the service correctly?

Comment: Can you post the output, without know which line its hard to be sure although from looking at your code i can see you do not instantiate the searchDaoImpl object which would throw a null pointer .

Answer (score 1):

You should not catch the exception in the `loadJsonFile()` method. It hides any exception and you don't see the real cause of failing tests.  Here is an improved `loadJsonFile()`.

```
@Before
public void loadJsonFile() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    searchParametersDto =  mapper.readValue(
        new File("D:\\productsData.json"),
        SearchParametersDto.class
    );
}
```